# What's the most accurate formal synonym masturbation?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Example sentence:

> The teenagers often engaged in visually-aided __.

I checked synonyms here: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/masturbation. And the closest one seems to be *self-sex*. However, this page: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=self%20sex it defines self-sex as something slightly different.

Comment: The term *masturbation* is NOT informal or slang.

Comment: What led you to believe that "masturbation" was not accurate or formal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Onanism: "Masturbation or self-gratification," Merriam Webster Collegiate

Comment: Onanism is not your best fit here.  It also means early withdrawal during coitus.  This is the literal etymology, deriving from the story of Onan in the Bible, who by the law of the time, was expected to impregnate his dead brother's widow, so that she might have children through his bloodline.  Onan withdrew prematurely, thus denying his sister-in-law his offspring (and having to support them).  How it became associated with masturbation is probably due to misinterpretation of the Biblical story.

Comment: "onanism" has religious connotations; the most accurate, neutral technical term is indeed just "masturbation".

Comment: @Mark As I interpret the OP, the poster knows the accuracy of "masturbation," but doesn't want to use it because his readers also know the meaning. He needs a word that will stall interpretation, a word that heads off self-congratulatory tittering. If the word has religious origins and other meanings, so much the better.